# Can someone suggest me how can i test or benchmark apache storm?

Tags: performance, testing, benchmarking, apache-storm

I need to test the performance of apache storm installed in multi node cluster.
I need some advice how can i do that? What aspects we need to consider?
is there any tools available in documentation?

I am quite new to this platform.
Appreciate if anybody could help

Comment: Mock an input with spout at a very fast pace and assert the output?

Answer (score 0):

Go through below link.

http://yahooeng.tumblr.com/post/64758709722/making-storm-fly-with-netty

get storm-perf-test code from

https://github.com/yahoo/storm-perf-test

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go through the links